Reference on why finding a feasible solution to the Set Partitioning problem is NP-Hard?
The set partitioning problem is an integer problem that looks as simple as this problem
$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\bf{P_2}\mathop {\min }\limits_{{x_i} \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}} }&{{x_1} + {x_2} + {x_3} + {x_4}}\\
{}&{{x_1} + {x_2} = 1}\\
{}&{{x_2} + {x_3} = 1}\\
{}&{{x_1} + {x_3} + {x_4} = 1}\\
{}&{{x_1} + {x_4} = 1}\\
{}&{{x_2} + {x_3} + {x_4} = 1}
\end{array}$
However, this lecture note said that "Even finding a feasible solution to a SPP is NP-hard" without showing any relevant reference. Therefore, my question is "Are there any reference on why finding a feasible solution to the Set Partitioning problem is NP-Hard ?"

It is one of Karp’s original 21 problems: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover

Does this mean that we can never find feasible solution in polynomial time. I feel very sad :(
